# How do I debug code from dylib in lldb

Tags: macos, debugging, rust

I have a sketch of code in rust that uses dynamically linked ffmpeg library.

How do I actually see the code of ffmpeg inside `lldb`.

I've modified portfile of `ffmpeg6` by adding this lines.

```
configure.args-append \
                    --disable-optimizations \
                    --enable-debug \
                    --disable-stripping \
```

But I still only see the assembler. Do I need to specify to lldb where to search for the source code somehow?